# How can I parallelize my builds across build agents?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, parallel-builds

I am currently running builds for 15 SKU's of the same product. In serial a full build of all SKU's takes just under three hours.

I have the resources to create a build farm that can handle the load of 1 build requiring 15 build agents and would like to make use of that fact.

I have used a TFS build template [I found online a few years ago on TFS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/09/14/parallelized-builds-with-tfs2010.aspx), I continued to use it on TFS2012 after I upgraded the template. Unfortunately that template won't easily be upgraded to work in TFS2013, and since it had shortcomings I would like to get a new template to start afresh in the new 2013 world. (Shortcomings it had were in terms of concurrent processing on singular tasks: labelling, associating work items with build numbers, private builds containing locked files.)

Since I've not found anything online yet, I am probably going to create my own parallel build template. Before I get too far in creating my own TFS parallel build template for TFS2013, I have to ask if there is a solution for this already available that I haven't yet stumbled across?

(I've done research here on SO and found many posts on the subject, but nothing with a full solution provided for a parallelized template that works in VS2013)

*edit: add link to source of parallel build template found for TFS2010*

Comment: What kind of parallelization are you doing? I can't imagine anything more then just partitioning the product into chunks that can be built separately. In that case you just use the default build workflow to build each chunk and a chainer build that triggers them in order of dependencies. Also if you're looking for build performance, it's always useful to try RAM disks. Performance gain will vary between builds but I've achieved 80% gain in certain projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. No out of box solution.

You are following the correct path with creating your own parallel wrapper. Microsoft themselves build every SKU of every part of Visual Studio & TFS when they do nightly builds and have heavily parallelised their build process to speed it up. This is however custom to them as every product builds differently.

Good luck.

Comment: This was the route I took as well. Our 3-4 hour builds are now running in ~35-40 mintues. Having to parallelize the builds on our own was a difficult problem to solve in TFS XAML builds, however with an upcoming move to Visual Studio Team Services online we can leverage the 'Build VNEXT' build processes which make parallelization quite simple.